# What roles/rights/groups does my DEPLOYING service principal need in order to configure EXTERNAL users in my Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I have configured my SQL Azure instance to support Managed Identity by setting an Azure Active Directory Admin, permitting Azure Active Directory authentication only and have assigned the Deploying Service Principal with the Azure 'Directory Readers' role.

If I login as myself to this database, I can issue the command

```
CREATE USER [my-managed-apiname] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

Successfully. But if I run the same thing via an Azure DevOps pipeline I'm told that

```
Principal 'my-managed-apiname' could not be resolved. Error message: 'AADSTS700016: Application with identifier 'GUID' was not found
```

Which I assume to be some sort of access issue from the deploying Service Principal's perspective? Am I right in this guess, and what do I need to change in either my Application Registration or Enterprise Application (related) that will make this work?

Comment: Some suggest that the SQL Server itself needs to have System Identity enabled and the system identity is the thing that requires the Directory Reader role rather than the admin group assigned to the server? But how would that let it work when I myself set the user rights on the same server?

Answer (score 1):

When you run Azure DevOps pipelines to access Azure resources, you should [create a service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#create-a-service-connection) first. And when a *Azure Resource Manager service connection* is created in Azure DevOps, a corresponding service principal would be created in Azure portal at the same time. Then please refer to the ticket [CREATE USER FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER by Service Principal](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2323#issuecomment-652907219) and add the service principal to the built-in Azure AD Role [Directory Readers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#directory-readers).

By the way, please make sure you're using the correct Application (client) ID.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer I’ve done all of this already, but with that role assigned results with the error stated in my question.

Comment: Please make sure you're using the correct Application (client) ID.